# Value of type String() cannot be converted into ArrayList

Tags: vb.net, mstest

I'm trying to automate test some codes and I can't seem to get this working on ListObject.

If I run the test it fails with an error:

> Value of type String() cannot be converted into ArrayList.

Here's what I'm trying:

**C# CODE:**

```
public string[] GetUserIdsFromPassId(string organisationId, string @PassId)
    {
        DbParameterCollection parameters = new DbParameterCollection();
        parameters.Add(new DbParameter("@OrganisationId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, organisationId));
        parameters.Add(new DbParameter("@PassId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, @PassId));

        string sql = "SELECT UserId FROM Orchestra WHERE OrganisationId=@OrganisationId AND PassId=@PassId";

        ListObject list = new ListObject(_Accessor);
        list.Read(sql, parameters);

        List<string> userIds = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in list.Table.Rows)
            userIds.Add(dataRow["UserId"].ToString());

        return userIds.ToArray();
    }
```

**AUTOMATE TESTING CODE:**

```
<TestClass()> Public Class Check_UserIdsFromPassId
    <TestMethod()> Public Sub GetUserIdsFromPassId()

        Dim organisationId As String = "1123"
        Dim PassId As String = "8110004"

        Dim UserId As string = String.Empty

        Dim ExpUserId As String = "00044"

        Dim DataServer As New DataServer()
        Dim Accessor = DataServer.GetAccessor()
        Dim _StandardHeader = New StandardHeader
        Dim _AuditProvider = New Audit.AuditProvider(_StandardHeader)
        Dim AD As New Ceridian.Administration.Authentication.AuthenticationData(Accessor, _AuditProvider)
        UserId = AD.GetUserIdsFromPassId(organisationId, PassId)
        Assert.AreEqual(ExpUserId, UserId)
        Console.WriteLine(ExpUserId)
        Console.WriteLine(UserId)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That method returns a `String` array so how exactly do you think that you can assign the result to a variable of type `String`?  I have no idea where the `ArrayList` comes in because there doesn't seem to be mention of one there.  Any reason you chose to not point out what line throws the exception?

Comment: By the way, what you have labelled "VB CODE" is actually C# code.

Comment: Point to this line : UserId = AD.GetUserIdsFromPassId(organisationId, PassId) it gives me the error "Value of type String() cannot be converted into ArrayList."

Comment: Which is the opposite of your question's title?

Comment: I do not know how to work this using array that is why asking if could be converted to string... Any further comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are expecting the function under test to return a string array with a single UserId (ExpUserId) you could just test the length of the array and the first value.

For instance, remove this line:

```
Dim UserId As string = String.Empty
```

Change the line that exercises the function under test to:

```
Dim UserId = AD.GetUserIdsFromPassId(organisationId, PassId)
```

and then confirm the returned array has a single correct value:

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, UserId.Count)
Assert.AreEqual(ExpUserId, UserId(0))
```

Comment: OK good news. If the answer helped then you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @duck, I need help on this one :  public string[] GetNamesFromExternalIds(string organisationId, string[] externalIds). I try to do it as said, and I got value of type string cannot be converted in string()

Comment: Do you want to post the whole code in a new question and we can take a look

Comment: Thanks @theduck, can you please have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888850/why-does-passing-variables-fails-with-error-value-type-string-cannot-be-conver