# Why does passing variables fails with error value type 'string' cannot be converted into 'string()'?

Tags: c#, vb.net, mstest

I'm trying to create an automated test for some C# code using VB.
Example: For the table Orchestra, i have 1 record for the organisation 1123, whereby user xxx has  value for externalId = null and name is Charm White. So my test would be to check if expected externalId is null and the name is charm white for that user.

However, when declaring variables of value type string[] externalIds in VB code, it  gives error :

> value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'string()'

Here's the C# code to be tested:

```
  public string[] GetNamesFromExternalIds(string organisationId, string[] externalIds)
    {
        string externalIdsString = null;
        foreach (string externalId in externalIds)
        {
            if (externalIdsString != null)
            {
                externalIdsString += ",";
            }
            externalIdsString += "'" + externalId + "'";
        }

        DbParameterCollection parameters = new DbParameterCollection();
        parameters.Add(new DbParameter("@OrganisationId",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 
        organisationId));

        string sql = string.Format(@"SELECT ExternalId, Name FROM Orchestra 
        WHERE ExternalId IN ({0}) AND OrganisationId = @OrganisationId",
        externalIdsString);

        ListObject list = new ListObject(_Accessor);
        list.Read(sql, parameters);

        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        foreach (string externalId in externalIds)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in list.Table.Rows)
            {
                if (dataRow["ExternalId"].ToString() == externalId)
                {
                    names.Add(dataRow["Name"].ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
            names.Add(null);
        }

        return names.ToArray();
    }
```

---

Here's what I'm trying into VB:

```
<TestClass()> Public Class UT_GetNamesFromExternalIds
    <TestMethod()> Public Sub GetNamesFromExternalIds()

        Dim organisationId As String = "1123"

        Dim externalIds() As String ={0}
        Dim user as string = "XXX"
        Dim names As String = String.Empty

        Dim ExpNames As String = "Charm White"
        Dim ExpexternalIds As String = Nothing

        Dim DataServer As New DataServer()
        Dim Accessor = DataServer.GetAccessor()
        Dim _StandardHeader = New StandardHeader
        Dim _AuditProvider = New Audit.AuditProvider(_StandardHeader)
        Dim AD As New Ceridian.Administration.Authentication.AuthenticationData(Accessor, _AuditProvider)

        externalIds = AD.GetNamesFromExternalIds(organisationId, 
         externalIds)

        Assert.AreEqual(1, externalIds.Count)
        Assert.AreEqual(ExpexternalIds, externalIds(0))


        Assert.AreEqual(ExpNames, names)

        Console.WriteLine(ExpNames)
        Console.WriteLine(names)

        Console.WriteLine(ExpexternalIds)
        Console.WriteLine(externalIds)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: The `names` variable is being tested but is never set to anything other than an empty string.

Comment: Which line in the code gives error?

Comment: You never show us where you declare the variable you're passing as the second argument here: `Dim externalIds = AD.GetNamesFromExternalIds(organisationId, externalIds)`.  Presumably it is declared as type `String` rather than type `String()`.  Rather a bad idea to be using the same variable name to assign the result to.

Comment: Is the `0001214` value the value you want to send to the function under test and `Charm White` the result you are expecting back?

Comment: @chetan this line it gives error on the externalIds :  Dim externalIds = AD.GetNamesFromExternalIds(organisationId, 
     externalIds)

Comment: The error message does not match the snippets in the question.  Seems you have an old version of the c# assembly floating around somewhere that did not yet use string[].  Favor a solution that contains both the vb.net and c# projects, so you can add a project reference in the vb.net project.  Use File > Add > Existing Project to kick that off.

Comment: `Dim externalIds() As String ={0}` This line will not compile with Option Strict On. You do have Option Strict On; yes? 0 is not a string. "0" is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to pass `0001214` into the function under test and are expecting `Charm White` as the result then you need to create a string array with your `0001214` value - pass it to the function and test the result:

```
Dim externalIds As String() = {"0001214"}
Dim organisationId As String = "1123"
Dim names = AD.GetNamesFromExternalIds(organisationId, externalIds)

Dim ExpNames As String = "Charm White"

Assert.AreEqual(1, names.Count)
Assert.AreEqual(ExpNames, names(0))
```

Also, remove the line:

```
Dim names As String = String.Empty
```

As the value returned from the function under test is a string array not a string. I have also moved your declaration of `organisationId` so that it is close to the code that uses it.

Comment: For the table Orchestra, i have 1 record for the organisation 1123, whereby user xxx has  value for externalId = null and name is Charm White. So my test would be to check if expected externalId is null and name is charm white for the user. I think i will it to pass that user as well right?

Comment: I don't think the function you are testing is going to ever find a record with an externalId of `Null` (as it is using a SQL `IN` to get the appropriate records). Is that a specific test that is required? Can you change the null value in your test data to be something you can test?

Comment: Yes I can try with the userid

Comment: OK - in order to test the function you are trying to test you need a record in your test data with an `externalId` that is not `null`. You can then pass that externalId to the function and make sure you get the correct name back. (And that the returned array only has one value)